# New to React :: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

Very new to React and I keep getting the warning above.  Have tried various methods to fix it, but had no luck, code is where I'm up to now.  Probably something very simple, but I just cannot see it.  I'm not running React through NodeJs and it's working apart from this warning.

**BuildList.js file**

```
    const ListItem = props => {
    return (
        <li key={`${props.title}${props.index}`} className="my-list" onClick={props.onDelete}>
            {props.title}
        </li>
    )
}
```

```
class BuildList extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {items: props.data};
}

addItemHandler() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        var newItem = prompt("Enter some text");

        if(newItem) {
            return {items: prevState.items.concat(newItem)};
        }
    });
}

deleteItemHandler(txt) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            return {items: prevState.items.filter(item => {
                    return item !== txt;
                }
            )};
        }
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p style={{'fontWeight': '700'}}>{this.props.intro}</p>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
                {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <ListItem key={item} title={item} onDelete={this.deleteItemHandler.bind(this, item)} />
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
            <button onClick={this.addItemHandler.bind(this)} className="btn btn-sm btn-success">Add</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

**app.js file**

```
(function(){

//Defaults
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');

//Final output
ReactDOM.render(
    [
        <BuildList data = {['Item 1','Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4']} intro="My first React list" />,             
    ], domContainer);
}) ()
```

***Below is the full warning message:***

```
react-dom.development.js:524 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See LINK TO WEBSITE for more information.
warningWithoutStack @   react-dom.development.js:524
warning @   react-dom.development.js:1012
warnForMissingKey   @   react-dom.development.js:14793
warnOnInvalidKey    @   react-dom.development.js:15259
reconcileChildrenArray  @   react-dom.development.js:15310
reconcileChildFibers    @   react-dom.development.js:15744
reconcileChildren   @   react-dom.development.js:18242
updateHostRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:18713
beginWork$1 @   react-dom.development.js:20336
beginWork$$1    @   react-dom.development.js:25902
performUnitOfWork   @   react-dom.development.js:24841
workLoopSync    @   react-dom.development.js:24817
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:24416
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:23844
updateContainer @   react-dom.development.js:27249
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:27674
unbatchedUpdates    @   react-dom.development.js:24579
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer    @   react-dom.development.js:27673
render  @   react-dom.development.js:27754
(anonymous) @   apps-dist.js:1
(anonymous) @   apps-dist.js:1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add key property to your `ListItem`component so the warning will disappear. But you  can't pass it through props because it's a React reserved prop.

```
const ListItem = props => {
  return (
    <li key={`${props.title}${props.index}`} className="my-list" onClick={props.onDelete}>
        {props.title}
    </li>
  )
}

<ul className="list-unstyled">
  {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <ListItem key={index} title={item} onDelete={this.deleteItemHandler.bind(this, item)} index={index} />
    )
  })}
</ul>
```

You should try to concatenate unique information to create your key prop. Using only the index of the `map` function is not a good practice.

Comment: Have just tried that and still get the same warning, along with react.development.js:255 Warning: ListItem: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop

Comment: Have updated my code, and edited my question, but still getting the warning

Comment: Try to change `key={item}` by `key={index}` then

Comment: Have tried that, still nothing.  Have tried what John Pierre Cena suggested, by adding <BuildList key={1}, this removed the warning, just not sure how though.  Everything I've read about this suggested that just adding key to ListItem and the const should have resolved it, but it didn't

Comment: It's highly unlikely to add key to `BuildList` component. I'm sure you need to add `key`prop on `ListItem` component. Could you try to refresh without cache ? Maybe your browser still keeping old version

Comment: that's what I thought too, have cleared the cache but still the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p style={{'fontWeight': '700'}}>{this.props.intro}</p>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
                {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <ListItem key={index} title={item} onDelete={this.deleteItemHandler.bind(this, item)} />
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
            <button onClick={this.addItemHandler.bind(this)} className="btn btn-sm btn-success">Add</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: also need to add key prop to `ListItem` component

Comment: That's not gonna make the warning go away

Comment: @Martin you need to add both the solution to your code (`<ListItem key={index}` and `<li key={props.key}`)

Comment: @Jigar Shah, tried that and still get the same two warning

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by this

```
//Final output
ReactDOM.render(
    [
        <BuildList data = {['Item 1','Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4']} intro="My first React list" />,             
    ], domContainer);
}) ()
```

Add key prop on BuildList

```
//Final output
ReactDOM.render(
    [
        <BuildList key={1} data = {['Item 1','Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4']} intro="My first React list" />,             
    ], domContainer);
}) ()
```

or don't make it an array

```
//Final output
ReactDOM.render(
<BuildList data = {['Item 1','Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4']} intro="My first React list" />,             
  , domContainer);
}) ()
```

Comment: you can edit your answer rather than adding another one.

Comment: @John Pierre Cena, can you explain why adding key={1} fixed this issue.  I need it as an array, because there are more options that I'm outputting, but they weren't relevant for my warning message

Comment: @Martin since you're rendering an array, react will ask for a key for each index for it to know which is which. In that case you can just store your BuildList element into an array variable and render it using array.map.

Answer (score 0):

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/unruffled-colden-o66t2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I have reproduced a minimal example using your code. After adding `key={index}`, i do not see any warnings. However if you remove "key" attribute, you will see warnings.